# Questions about nprinting in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have two questions about nprinting (i dont found tag nprinting):

First of all, how it works the feature "Slides" on ppt in Nprinting?

Second, if possible to select 3 items from a list of 10 items and just show this 3 items configured previously the feature "Slides".

For example,

- item 2 -> Slides: 2-4
- item 4 -> Slides: 8-10
- item 5 -> Slides 11-15

i just want to show, with the on demand button, this slides only, not all.

Comment: Please consider re-wording your question, I'm not sure what your questions are

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you had to create a N-tables with autonumber related with all of your items(in script), so name item 1->1, name item 2->2 ... and add in Nprinting Page this field for each pagination.

hope it helps.